# Auto indentation inside two parenthesis - Vim

Tags: function, vim, parameters, indentation, auto-indent

I want vim to auto indent like this

```
int function_that_takes_long_arguments(long_argument_1,|
                                                       ^
                                              This is the cursor.
```

Press enter

```
int function_that_takes_long_arguments(long_argument_1,<enter>
>   >   >   >   >   >   >   >   >   ...|);
    ^                                ^ ^
(tab - 4 spaces)                     | |
                 (Add spaces to align) |
                      (I want the cursor to auto indent here)
```

Start writing other arguments

```
int function_that_takes_long_arguments(long_argument_1,<enter>
>   >   >   >   >   >   >   >   >   ...long_argument_2,<enter>
>   >   >   >   >   >   >   >   >   ...long_argument_3);
```

Another Example:

```
void function(argument_1, argument_2, argument_3,<enter>
>   >   >   ..argument_4, argument_5);
```

Comment: well I would be interested in a working solution too (I think it is possible, but not easy). However I do work around that issue by using a linter that can correct that (in my case rubocop, which has an autocorrect function). Maybe there is something for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indenting in C/C++ files is typically managed by internal routine (see also `:h C-indenting`). The supported options are explained in detail under `:h cinoptions-values`.

So assuming you have `setlocal cindent` in the current buffer (including simply `filetype indent on` which sets `cindent` for a few filetypes/extensions automatically), it's enough to do usual

> ~.vim/after/indent/c.vim

```
setlocal cinoptions=(0
```